# Brown spot on (in?) dell screen

Tags: display

I have had my dell screen in storage for the last couple weeks.  When I turned it on today I noticed a brown spot on it.  There is a picture below.  (I am hopding a dvd in front of the screen for size).

The smaller inner circle of the dot is about 7 mm (0.3 inches).  The outer circle is a bit larger than a quater.

The interesting thing is that the circle is somewhat transparent.  When there is text behind the circle the text is still readable.

Has anyone had this problem before?  What was your solution?  I have tried cleaning the screen but it seems like the screen has an internal error.  (I wonder if it could have gotten some dirt in it or if it could have got hit by something.

[image]

Comment: Looks like physical damage to me.

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone had this problem before?

I haven't.

> What was your solution?

I would buy a new screen.

> I have tried cleaning the screen but it seems like the screen has an internal error. (I wonder if it could have gotten some dirt in it or if it could have got hit by something.

It got hit by something. LCD displays are pressure sensitive - try pressing your finger hard into a clear area of the screen - you'll see a shadow that takes a second to dissipate. Pressing harder, or a sharp impact, will cause permanent damage.

Comment: +1. It's also fairly likely that the damage will slowly expand in size, i've seen that happen a few times.